# How To Change Views With A Filter Bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to coding and swift and am trying to use a bar to change views. I am trying to use a bar to change the views when one of the filters is tapped (see images). In my filter bar I have two options - "Dog" (shows an image of a dog), and "Items" which displays a simple list of random items (ItemsView). I have three views. The Home view which is the view when the app is launched and the default selection is dog, so the home view should show the filter bar with a photo of a dog underneath it. When "Items" is tapped, I want the photo of the dog to change to the list (the DogView should no longer be displayed and the ListView should be displayed).

[This is what the code looks like when it runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO4pU.png)

The photo shows what it currently looks like. When items is tapped the only thing that happens is the blue bar goes underneath the word "items". The dog photo remains.

The code for my Home Page is:

```
struct Home: View {
    
    // MARK: For Smooth Sliding Effect
    @Namespace var animation
    
    @State private var selectedHomeFilter: HomeFilterViewModel = .dog
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        homeFilterBar
        
        DogView()
        
    }

    var homeFilterBar: some View {
        
        HStack {
            ForEach(HomeFilterViewModel.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item.title)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(selectedHomeFilter == item ? .semibold: .regular)
                        .foregroundColor(selectedHomeFilter == item ? .black: .gray)
                    
                    if selectedHomeFilter == item {
                        Capsule()
                            .foregroundColor(Color("StriderLightBlue"))
                            .frame(height: 3)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "filter", in: animation)
                        
                    } else {
                        Capsule()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.clear))
                            .frame(height: 3)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        self.selectedHomeFilter  = item
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        .overlay(Divider().offset(x: 0, y: 16))
    }
}
```

The ViewModel for the filter bar is:

```
enum HomeFilterViewModel: Int, CaseIterable {
    
    case dog
    case Items
    
    var title: String {
        
        switch self {
            
        case .dog: return "Dog"
        case .Items: return "Items"
        }
    }
}
```

My DogView is:

```
struct DogView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Image("DogImage")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
    }
}
```

The code for the ItemsView is:

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
           
            Text("Rubber")
            Text("Pencil")
            Text("Ruler")
            
        }
    }
}
```

When "Items" is tapped I want the ItemsView to be displayed instead of DogView but am unsure how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At least the dog is cute! Seriously, in the  body of `Home`, you have `homeFilterBar` and `DogView()`. You never even call `ItemsView`, so of course it doesn't show. `DogView()` and `ItemsView` need to be alternate branches of a conditional that uses `selectedHomeFilter` to choose which to show.

Comment: @Yrb Thank you! Yes, sorry I didn't include ItemsView in the body because I was unsure of how I would integrate it. I tried using if and else statements to do this but was unsuccessful. Do you know how you would go about structuring the code? that uses selectedHomeFilter? Thanks

Comment: Google "swiftui view conditional" There are many ways. Which one you use depends on what you are trying to accomplish in the end. Making this work may not actually make your end result work.